# How to turn off vertical y axis bar in MATLAB plot?

Tags: matlab, graph, charts

How do I turn off the black line on a vertical y-axis?

I tried using the following to set its color to white so that it appears hidden. However, I am also using the grid lines, and if I do this they also turn white:

```
set(gca,'YColor',[1 1 1]);  % Sets y-axis and gridlines to white color (represented by '1 1 1')
```

I also found I can do the following to fix the issue:

***Plot a white line exactly where the y-axis ranges***

Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot a white line exactly where the y-axis ranges